# Domain Controller's DNS NIC configuration

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, best-practices

I've seen conflicting information on this online, but say you have an environment with two domain controllers: one Forest, one Site, one Domain; simple as it gets.

How should each domain controller's NIC be configured with respect to DNS?

1. Assuming both are running DNS Server, should `DC1` should have it's own canonical IP address (i.e. not loopback address) as the primary DNS and the secondary should be `DC2`? Rinse and repeat for `DC2`. Seems logical to me.
2. Does this have any impact on replication?
3. I'm assuming forwarders/root hints are irrelevant with respect to Active Directory?